# My menu does not display a hamburger icon anymore

Tags: javascript, html, css

After changing some styles, the hamburger icon for mobile phones does not display anymore, how can I bring it back? also what would be the best way to add a little bit more white space above and under the menu but keep the position the same?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="xBxHack" />
<nav id="mainNav" class="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">my<strong>Nav</strong></a></div>
        <label class="navBars" for="xBxHack">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <ul id="menu" class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.mainNav {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  max-height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  top:35%;
}
.mainNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mainNav .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 1.55em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: relative;
}
.mainNav .logo:hover:before {
  background: #292938;
}
.mainNav .logo:before {
  content: "";
  background: #3C91E6;
  z-index: -1;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mainNav .logo a {
  color: #efefef;
}
.mainNav .menu {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size:10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mainNav .menu a {
  color: #292938;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mainNav .navBars {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  float: right;
  /*USER SELECTION*/
  -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#xBxHack {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
}
#xBxHack:checked ~ nav .menu {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mainNav {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mainNav .navBars {
    display: none;
  }
  .mainNav .container {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mainNav .logo {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .mainNav .menu {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    /*POSITION*/
    position: static;
  }
  .mainNav .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mainNav .menu a {
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var myNav = {
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDOM();
            this.browserWidth();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDOM: function() {
            this.navBars = $(".navBars");
            this.xBxHack = $("#xBxHack");
            this.navMenu = $("#menu");
        },
        browserWidth: function() {
            $(window).resize(this.bindEvents.bind(this));
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            var width = window.innerWidth;

            if (width < 600) {
                this.navBars.click(this.animate.bind(this));
                this.navMenu.hide();
                this.xBxHack[0].checked = false;
            } else {
                this.resetNav();
            }
        },
        animate: function(e) {
            var checkbox = this.xBxHack[0];
            !checkbox.checked ?
                this.navMenu.slideDown() :
                this.navMenu.slideUp();

        },
        resetNav: function() {
            this.navMenu.show();
        }
    };
    myNav.init();
});
```

In this jsfiddle you can see that the icon does not appear when the screen is small: https://jsfiddle.net/quehf3x9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure that you're loading the [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) library. That wasn't being loaded in the JS Fiddle example. So I included a link to a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome).

Secondly, add a width, height and background color to the CSS for the navbars:

```
.mainNav .navBars {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
color: #111;
}
```

See my updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quehf3x9/2/) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you! could you also tell me how I can add more white space above/under the menu but keep the rest in the middle?

Comment: If you add some padding to `.mainNav` then that would do that. For example you could add something like: `padding: 10px 0;`. Here's an updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quehf3x9/4/) example.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! maybe my OCD is failing but the text is a bit off the middle, it looks like it is a little bit above it, after that it is perfect

Comment: @Melissa that could be corrected by adding some padding to `.mainNav .menu`. For example, you could add `padding: 5px 0 0;`. Here's an updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quehf3x9/5/).

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with your fiddle above. The first is that you did not include the font awesome library. The code does not know what to do with the `fa fa-bars` classes. To include an external library in jsfiddle:

1. Find a CDN where the file is hosted
2. Copy the path to the file
3. Paste it in the left sidebar in the *External Resources* section.
4. Select the *+* icon to add the resource to the fiddle.

Once the file is loaded, you can see from the developer tools (open the tools by selecting <kbd>F12</kbd>) that the class is applied but the icon color is white. You'll want to add some CSS to color the icon such as:

```
label i {
    color: #333;
}
```

I've made these two changes and updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/quehf3x9/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things-

First one you are missing to include [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) library

Secondly the color of icon is white. So you won't be able to see it even if you include the library, changing the color will do the trick `<i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:black;"></i>`

```css
 .mainNav {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  max-height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  top:35%;
}
.mainNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mainNav .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 1.55em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: relative;
}
.mainNav .logo:hover:before {
  background: #292938;
}
.mainNav .logo:before {
  content: "";
  background: #3C91E6;
  z-index: -1;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mainNav .logo a {
  color: #efefef;
}
.mainNav .menu {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size:10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mainNav .menu a {
  color: #292938;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mainNav .navBars {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  float: right;
  /*USER SELECTION*/
  -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#xBxHack {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
}
#xBxHack:checked ~ nav .menu {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mainNav {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mainNav .navBars {
    display: none;
  }
  .mainNav .container {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mainNav .logo {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .mainNav .menu {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    /*POSITION*/
    position: static;
  }
  .mainNav .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mainNav .menu a {
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<input type="checkbox" id="xBxHack" />
<nav id="mainNav" class="mainNav">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><a href="#">my<strong>Nav</strong></a></div>
  <label class="navBars" for="xBxHack">
   <i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:black;"></i>
      
  </label>
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: use my codepens : https://codepen.io/nullqube/pen/bRjRMK   or   https://codepen.io/nullqube/pen/RgMvbW  :D